# Calling function doesn't work.. I got no idea what is going on

Tags: c

So in short I want to do this:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer++, executes, execute);
```

but here the pointer is never increased to the next function (I tried printing it and it keeps printing 0, until my computer eventually crashed.)

Now what I did was this:

```
pointer++;
createProcesswithPipe(pointer, executes, execute);
```

Seems logical right?

Well now I get this error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Okey so now that I got some information I'll also share some more as it seems Segmentation fault is the main problem here...

So this is a recursive function and the first thing I do as I enter it is to print out the pointer value (this is just to check it) and when my code doesn't contain the recursive part, when I comment out this part:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer, executes, execute);
```

the printf at the start works and prints 0 then I get segmentation fault.

When it is not commented out it doesn't even print out the first 0 it just closes the program with the error segmentation fault.

So in other words when it is not commented out it seems like the whole program crashes before it even reaches that part of the code?

Comment: Something is wrong. But it's in the code that we cannot see.

Comment: I'm glad someone pointed that the problem is in the code we can not see, instead of trying to answer.

Comment: I just added some more info I could add all of the code but it's 130 lines and I don't think people would want to read all of that :P

Comment: There is a reasonable compromise between 4 and 130.

Comment: We don't want to read all that. So make an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer++, executes, execute);
```

Is the same as:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer, executes, execute);
pointer++;
```

---

**On the other hand, this code**:

```
pointer++;
createProcesswithPipe(pointer, executes, execute);
```

Is the same as:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer + 1, executes, execute);
pointer++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the pre-incremet

```
createProcesswithPipe(++pointer, executes, execute);
```

++pointer increments pointer before evaluating the expression
while pointer++ evaluates it before incrementing. If you use the pre-increment, you shouldn't need an extra line. Or, you can do this:

```
createProcesswithPipe(pointer+=1, executes, execute);
```